# How do I append rows to an array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, matrix, append

I have an array which is a 1X3 matrix, where:
    column 1 = x coordinate
    column 2 = y coordinate
    column 3 = direction of vector.

I am tracking a series of points along a path.
At each point i want to store the x,y and direction back into the array, as a row.

So in the end, my array has grown vertically, with more and more rows that represents points along the path.

Im struggling to build this function inside a class.
Help plz?

Xx

Comment: You may want to re-structure your question. Please have a read of http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the `append` function. But you should seriously take a look at [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) for using matrices in python

Answer (score 0):

Use `.append('item-goes-here')` to append.

Answer (score 0):

```
# This is your matrix 1x3
matrix = []

# Use a list to store (x, y, direction)
data = [x, y, direction]

# To add data to the matrix use `append` on matrix list
matrix.append(point)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: x = [1,2]

In [2]: y = [3,4]

In [3]: x+y
Out[3]: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```